# Getting all the users same child in Firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently building an app in Firebase and I want to get all the users parking spaces but the problem is that my code doesn't retrieve parking spaces child of each user from firebase, it doesn't get any data.

This is my code:

```
public ArrayList<ParkingSpace> retrieve() {
    db.child("Users").child("Parking Spaces").orderByChild("adress").equalTo("park1").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);
        }
        ...
    };
}

private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {   
    ParkingSpace space = dataSnapshot.getValue(ParkingSpace.class);
    space.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
    parkingsSpaces.add(space);
}
```

This is the tree:

[image: database]

Comment: What's the question or problem?

Comment: the problem is that this code doesn't retrieve parking spaces child of each user from firebase

Answer (score 0):

```
db.child("Users").child("Parking Spaces").orderByChild("adress").equalTo("park1")
```

This code will retreive each parking space with value = "park1".
Whereas your parkingSpace values are objects with inner attributes. I don't think Firebase provide ways to retreive them directly by filtering by their attribute.

You have to filter the response inside your application:

```
public ArrayList<ParkingSpace> retrieve() {
    db.child("Users").child("Parking Spaces").orderByChild("adress").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);
        }
        ...
    };
}

 private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ParkingSpace space = dataSnapshot.getValue(ParkingSpace.class);
        if ( "park1".equals(space.getAdress)) {
            space.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            parkingsSpaces.add(space);
        }
    }
```